# Creating a file with with size one page and fill it with \0 bytes

Tags: c, file, io

I was asked to create a page file with size of one page and fill it with \0 bytes. I know how to create a file but I do not understand the concept of page. Also How do I implement absolute addressing ie, reading and writing in terms of blocks in c language.

Comment: put what you have tried so far..

Comment: you can read some books to understand the concept of page

Comment: could you please suggest a good article/reference on this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
  char *p = malloc(pagesize);
  memset(p, 0, pagesize);
  FILE *f = fopen("pagefile", "w+b");
  fwrite(p, pagesize, 1, f);
  fclose(f);
```

How big your page is, depends on your system but I would guess at 4096 bytes.